# Trying to fill jtable with arraylist, but not working

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to populate a jTable using an arrayList, but I am not able to. I have 4 classes. The problem I think is that I cannot equate the manchester arraylist in the SoccerViewPlayer class to the user-inputted team arraylist in the SoccerEnterPlayer class.

The SoccerViewPlayer class

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.awt.ScrollPane;

public class SoccerViewPlayers {

    // Frame Classes - GUI
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTable table;
    //private String[] columns = new String[] {"Name","Age", "Gender", "Team Level" };
    String[] columns = {"Player Name","Gender", "Age", "Team Level","Position","Overall Shots","Shots On Target", "Goals", "Saves"};
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SoccerViewPlayers window = new SoccerViewPlayers();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public SoccerViewPlayers() {
        initialize();
    }


    private void initialize() {
        // Deals with program frame.
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        String[][] werty = new String[][]{
            {}
            //{"Sandra","Female","21", "Varsity","Striker","17","8", "5", "0"},

        };


        table = new JTable(werty, columns);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        ArrayList<SoccerPlayer> manchester = ArrayList(); 
        Object rowData[] = new Object [9]; 
        for(int i = 0; i < manchester.size(); i++)
        {
            rowData[0] = manchester.get(i).getPlayerName();
            rowData[1] = manchester.get(i).getGender();
            rowData[2] = manchester.get(i).getage();
            rowData[3] = manchester.get(i).getTeamLevel();
            rowData[4] = manchester.get(i).getPosition();
            rowData[5] = manchester.get(i).getOverallShots();
            rowData[6] = manchester.get(i).getShotsOnTarget();
            rowData[7] = manchester.get(i).getGoals();
            rowData[8] = manchester.get(i).getSaves();
            model.addRow(rowData);  
        }

    }

The Soccer Class
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Soccer {
    public  ArrayList<SoccerPlayer> SoccerPlayers; 

    public void addPlayers(String PlayerName, String Gender, int age, String teamLevel, String position, int shotsOnTarget, int overallShots, int goals, int saves)
    {
        SoccerPlayers.add(new SoccerPlayer(PlayerName, Gender, age,  teamLevel, position, shotsOnTarget, overallShots, goals, saves));

The SoccerPlayer class
public class SoccerPlayer {
    private String PlayerName;
    private String position; 
    private String Gender;
    private int shotsOnTarget; 
    private int overallShots;
    private int goals; 
    private int saves; 
    private String teamLevel; 
    private int age;

    public SoccerPlayer(String PlayerName, String Gender, int age,   String teamLevel, String position, int shotsOnTarget, int overallShots, int goals, int saves) {
        this.PlayerName = PlayerName; 
        this.age = age; 
        this.Gender = Gender; 
        this.teamLevel = teamLevel; 
        this.position = position; 
        this.shotsOnTarget = shotsOnTarget; 
        this.overallShots = overallShots; 
        this.goals = goals; 
        this.saves = saves; 
    }


    public String getDetails()
    {
        System.out.println("Team Level:" + teamLevel);
        System.out.println("Player Name:" + PlayerName);
        System.out.println("Gender:" + Gender);
        System.out.println("Age:" + age);
        System.out.println("Position:" + position);
        System.out.println("Shots:" + overallShots);
        System.out.println("Shots On Target:" + shotsOnTarget);
        System.out.println("Goals:" + goals);
        System.out.println("Saves:" + saves); 
        return null; 
    }
    public String getPlayerName()
    {
        return PlayerName;
    }

    public String getGender()
    {
        return Gender; 
    }

    public String getTeamLevel()
    {
        return teamLevel; 
    }

    public String getPosition()
    {
        return position; 
    }

    public int getShotsOnTarget()
    {
        return shotsOnTarget; 
    }

    public int getOverallShots()
    {
        return overallShots; 
    }

    public int getGoals()
    {
        return goals; 
    }

    public int getSaves()
    {
        return saves; 

    }

    public int getage()
    {
        return age; 
    }
}

The SoccerEnterPlayer class
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class SoccerEnterPlayer extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private static SoccerEnterPlayer frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frame = new SoccerEnterPlayer();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public SoccerEnterPlayer() {

        String[] genders = { "Male", "Female" };
        String[] teamLevel = {"Varsity", "Junior Varsity"};
        String[] positions = {"Goalkeeper", "Defender", "Midfielder", "Striker"};

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(105, 56, 84, 16);
        contentPane.add(textArea);

        JTextArea textArea_1 = new JTextArea();
        textArea_1.setBounds(300, 56, 84, 16);
        contentPane.add(textArea_1);

        JTextArea textArea_5 = new JTextArea();
        textArea_5.setBounds(300, 118, 84, 16);
        contentPane.add(textArea_5);

        JTextArea textArea_6 = new JTextArea();
        textArea_6.setBounds(105, 177, 84, 16);
        contentPane.add(textArea_6);

        JTextArea textArea_7 = new JTextArea();
        textArea_7.setBounds(204, 177, 84, 16);
        contentPane.add(textArea_7);

        JTextArea textArea_8 = new JTextArea();
        textArea_8.setBounds(300, 177, 84, 16);
        contentPane.add(textArea_8);

        JLabel lblPlayerNamer = new JLabel("Player Name");
        lblPlayerNamer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblPlayerNamer.setBounds(105, 28, 84, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblPlayerNamer);

        JLabel lblGender = new JLabel("Gender");
        lblGender.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblGender.setBounds(204, 28, 84, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblGender);

        JLabel lblAge = new JLabel("Age");
        lblAge.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblAge.setBounds(300, 28, 84, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblAge);

        JLabel lblTeamLevel = new JLabel("Team Level");
        lblTeamLevel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblTeamLevel.setBounds(105, 90, 84, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblTeamLevel);

        JLabel lblPosition = new JLabel("Position");
        lblPosition.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblPosition.setBounds(204, 90, 84, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblPosition);

        JLabel lblOverallShots = new JLabel("Overall Shots");
        lblOverallShots.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblOverallShots.setBounds(300, 90, 84, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblOverallShots);

        JLabel lblShotsOnTarget = new JLabel("Shots on Target");
        lblShotsOnTarget.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        lblShotsOnTarget.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblShotsOnTarget.setBounds(91, 149, 114, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblShotsOnTarget);

        JLabel lblGoals = new JLabel("Goals");
        lblGoals.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblGoals.setBounds(204, 149, 84, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblGoals);

        JLabel lblSaves = new JLabel("Saves");
        lblSaves.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblSaves.setBounds(300, 149, 84, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblSaves);

        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(genders);
        comboBox.setToolTipText("");
        comboBox.setMaximumRowCount(2);
        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(1);
        comboBox.setBounds(198, 52, 100, 27);
        contentPane.add(comboBox);

        JComboBox comboBox_1 = new JComboBox(teamLevel);
        comboBox_1.setToolTipText("");
        comboBox_1.setSelectedIndex(1);
        comboBox_1.setMaximumRowCount(2);
        comboBox_1.setBounds(105, 114, 100, 27);
        contentPane.add(comboBox_1);

        JComboBox comboBox_2 = new JComboBox(positions);
        comboBox_2.setBounds(204, 114, 84, 27);
        contentPane.add(comboBox_2);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Submit");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(300, 221, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(e->{
            Soccer team = new Soccer();
            team.addPlayers(textArea.getText(), comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(), Integer.parseInt(textArea_1.getText()), comboBox_1.getSelectedItem().toString(), comboBox_2.getSelectedItem().toString(), Integer.parseInt(textArea_5.getText()), Integer.parseInt(textArea_6.getText()), Integer.parseInt(textArea_7.getText()), Integer.parseInt(textArea_8.getText()));
            new SoccerFrame();
            frame.dispose();
        });

        }
}
```

Comment: Questions here need to show the minimum code possible that demonstrates the problem, and they need to contain a specific problem fault. "Not working" is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over an empty list:

```
ArrayList<SoccerPlayer> manchester = ArrayList(); 
Object rowData[] = new Object [9]; 
for(int i = 0; i < manchester.size(); i++)
{
    ...
}
```

`manchester.size()` is 0.

You have to add your data to the manchaster list at first. Like:

```
ArrayList<SoccerPlayer> manchester = ArrayList(); 
manchaster.add(new SoccerPlayer("Tom", "male", ....));

Object rowData[] = new Object [9]; 
for(int i = 0; i < manchester.size(); i++)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the manchester arraylist = to this arraylist:

Comment: Soccer team = new Soccer();
            team.addPlayers(textArea.getText(), comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(), Integer.parseInt(textArea_1.getText()), comboBox_1.getSelectedItem().toString(), comboBox_2.getSelectedItem().toString(), Integer.parseInt(textArea_5.getText()), Integer.parseInt(textArea_6.getText()), Integer.parseInt(textArea_7.getText()), Integer.parseInt(textArea_8.getText()));
            new SoccerFrame();
            frame.dispose();

Comment: If you add an getter for the ArrayList into the Soccer Class, you can type `manchaster = Soccer.getPlayers()` or something like this.